# Statistics probability subscription and percentages

Tags: probability, statistics

> "Channel One" is an educational television network for which participating secondary schools are equipped with TV sets in every classroom. It has been found that 70% of secondary schools subscribe to Channel One, where of these subscribers 5% never use Channel One while 25% claim to use it more than 5 times per week.
>
> Find the probability that a randomly selected secondary school subscribes to Channel One and uses it more than 5 times per week.

I have reasoned that

$P(A) = 0.7$ from the number of secondary schools subscribed to channel one

$P(B) = 0.25$ claim to use it more than 5 times per week.

\begin{align} P(A \cup B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)\\
&= 0.7 + 0.25 - (0.70)(0.25)\\
&= 0.775
\end{align}

What is the correct answer and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is that for a randomly selected secondary school, that this school subscribes and uses it more than 5 times per week.

So we want
$$P(A \cap B)= 0.70 \cdot 0.25$$
You computed the wrong probability, the 25% is for the schools that are subscribed, so give that we are part of the 70%, 25% of those schools claim to use the subscription more than 5 times per week.

Comment: Thank you and all the best!